# Maven Not Downloading pom.xml and .jar File

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have the following settings.xml file in my project organizationsservice:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>${env.MAVEN_REPO_USERNAME}</username>
      <password>${env.MAVEN_REPO_PASSWORD}</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>${env.MAVEN_REPO_USERNAME}</username>
      <password>${env.MAVEN_REPO_PASSWORD}</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>saathratri-profile</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>default-maven-virtual</name>
          <url>https://saathratri.jfrog.io/artifactory/default-maven-virtual</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>default-maven-virtual</name>
          <url>https://saathratri.jfrog.io/artifactory/default-maven-virtual</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>saathratri-profile</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

I include the following in my pom.xml:

```
...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.saathratri.organizations.domain</groupId>
            <artifactId>saathratri-organizations-domain</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>   
...
```

However, when I run the following command `mvn -s settings.xml dependency:list`, only the maven-metadata.xml file is downloaded. The saathratri-organizations-domain-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar nor the
saathratri-organizations-domain-2.0-SNAPSHOT.pom are not downloaded.

See below output from the command:

```
➜  organizationsservice git:(master) ✗ mvn -s settings.xml dependency:list        
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------< com.saathratri.organizations:organizationsservice >----------
[INFO] Building Organizationsservice 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from snapshots: https://saathratri.jfrog.io/artifactory/default-maven-virtual/com/saathratri/organizations/domain/saathratri-organizations-domain/2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded from snapshots: https://saathratri.jfrog.io/artifactory/default-maven-virtual/com/saathratri/organizations/domain/saathratri-organizations-domain/2.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (376 B at 565 B/s)
INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ organizationsservice ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:jar:2.4.4:compile
[INFO]    org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.7.1:test
...
```

Please advise why the pom and jar are not being downloaded.

Thanks and Happy Father's Day to all dads.

Edit1: The Artifactory URL:

````
https://saathratri.jfrog.io/artifactory/default-maven-local/com/saathratri/organizations/domain/saathratri-organizations-domain/2.0-SNAPSHOT/``` has the following contents:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9Qwj.png
````

Edit2:

```
mvn -s settings.xml dependency:list
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/jboss/web/servlet-api/2.1.0.GA/servlet-api-2.1.0.GA.pom
Downloaded: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/jboss/web/servlet-api/2.1.0.GA/servlet-api-2.1.0.GA.pom (195 B at 0.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/jboss/web/servlet-api/2.1.0.GA/servlet-api-2.1.0.GA.jar
Downloaded: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/jboss/web/servlet-api/2.1.0.GA/servlet-api-2.1.0.GA.jar (84 KB at 90.8 KB/sec)
```

Comment: Why do you expect `dependency:list` to download JARs?

Comment: According to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-a-custom-maven-settings-xml, they run ```dependency:list``` and the JARs download; please see Edit2.

Comment: Why do you need this? Why not just run a normal build like `mvn clean verify`?

Comment: Have you tried mvn install?

Answer (score 0):

Are the pom and jar actually present in the correct place in your jfrog?

Comment: Yes, please see Edit1 above.